# uiInstance.close() has no effect

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code inside a script for a Google Spreadsheet:

```
var uiInstance;

function displayDialog() {
 uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
  .setWidth(130)
  .setHeight(130);
 uiInstance.add(uiInstance.createLabel("foo"));
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiInstance, 'bar');
}
```

This dialog is intended to inform the user the script is calculating something and I want to close the dialog again once the script has finished its work. If I use

```
uiInstance.close();
```

inside or outside the function nothing seems to happen though; the dialog remains opened until the user closes it. Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to "return" to effectively close the uiInstance, `return` is needed to reflect any change you made to the Ui, including closing it.

try

```
return uiInstance.close();
```

---

**EDIT following your comment :**

UiApp instances can only be closed from a handler function, I thought that was how you were using it (but I might have been wrong).

Below is a small code example :

```
function displayDialog() {
  var uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
  .setWidth(130)
  .setHeight(130);
  uiInstance.add(uiInstance.createLabel("foo"));
  var handler = uiInstance.createServerHandler('closeDialog');
  uiInstance.add(uiInstance.createButton('close',handler));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiInstance, 'bar');
}

function closeDialog(){
  return UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
}
```

There is also a tricky workaround that can "simulate" a user action. It uses a property of some widgets to trigger a handler function when they change value. In the example below I used a checkBox to start the process

It will close the dialog when the task in doStuf is done.

```
function displayDialog() {
  var uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
  .setWidth(130)
  .setHeight(130);
  uiInstance.add(uiInstance.createLabel("foo"));
  var handler = uiInstance.createServerHandler('doStuf');
  var chk = uiInstance.createCheckBox().setValue(true).setId('chk').setVisible(false);
  chk.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
  uiInstance.add(chk);
  chk.setValue(false,true)// This actually calls the doStuf function (using the handler)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiInstance, 'bar');
}

function doStuf(){
  Utilities.sleep(5000);// replace with something useful ...
  return UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
}
```

Comment: Probably I just don't get what you mean, still I can't make it work; If I have a function like { displayDialog(); doStuff(); closeDialog(); } what needs closeDialog() to look like? And do I have to change displayDialog() as well?

Comment: Thank you =)! I needed this because the "doStuff" task takes quite some time to finish (> 1min) and I wanted the user to know if (or that) it is still working

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
uiInstance = uiInstance.close();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(uiInstance, 'bar');
```